# Select last element quickly after a .Split()

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have this code :

```
stringCutted = myString.Split("/"). // ???
```

and I'd like to store in `stringCutted` the last element of the `string[]` after the split, directly, quickly, without storing the splitted array in a variable and access to that element with `array[array.length]`.

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: string 'Cutted' ??????

Comment: a string that has been cut :)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, it's easy using LINQ to Objects:

```
stringCutted = myString.Split('/').Last();
```

Note that [`Last()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) (without a predicate) is optimized for the case where the source implements `IList<T>` (as a single-dimensional array does) so this *won't* iterate over the whole array to find the last element. On the other hand, that optimization is undocumented...

Comment: Yes, that's becuase of LINQ, you need to add a 'using System.Linq;' to your code.

Comment: This works, but not ever. In fact `Split("/")` put me an error. `Split('/')` works...

Comment: @markzzz: Fixed. I was assuming you were posting working code to start with (your question uses double quotes).

Comment: Yeah. In fact that was the error :) I tried with Last()before posting the question...! heh, thanks

Answer (score 32):

```
stringCutted=myString.Split("/").Last()
```

But, just FYI, if you're trying to get a filename from a path, this works heaps better:

```
var fileName=System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\\some\path\and\filename.txt"); 
// yields: filename.txt
```

Comment: great answer, but I'm curious why this works better than splitting the file with the above method?

Answer (score 15):

Since you want a solution that returns the last element directly, quickly, without store the splitted array, i think this may be useful:

```
stringCutted = myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ

```
"t/e/s/t".Split("/").Last();
```

Answer (score 2):

For using this code, I skip last element from the `Url` link.

```
string url = Request.Url.ToString().Substring(0, Request.Url.ToString().LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Addition:**

When string format like `'a/b/c/d'` then

```
yourstring.Split("/").Last();
```

When string format like `\head_display\27_[Item A]\head_image\original_image\1_Item A.png`

```
yourstring.Split("\\").Last();
```

first '\' actually to skip second '\'