# How to split a string at the last '.' value

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like

```
    string str = "123.1.1.QWE";
    string[] seqNum = textBox1.Text.Split('.');
```

I want to split the string at the last . value and have to split into two  strings only like

```
seqNum[0]="123.1.1";
seqNum[1]="QWE";
```

How can I split it into two strings at the last index.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this string follows file name semantics, have you tried the `System.IO.Path` static methods `GetExtension()` and `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string str = "123.1.1.QWE";    
int index = str.LastIndexOf(".");
string[] seqNum = new string[] {str.Substring(0, index), str.Substring(index + 1)};
```

Comment: Looks good. Could also do this though, which is basically the same, but with a slightly simpler syntax: `string[] seqNum = new[] {str.Take(index), str.Skip(index + 1)};`

Comment: This also works :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256873/select-last-element-quickly-after-a-split

Comment: @Curiousity this only works when OP wants the last part of the splitted string, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string str = "123.1.1.QWE";
            string[] seqnum = new string[2];
            foreach (char ch in str)
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(ch) || ch == '.')
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    int indx = str.IndexOf(ch);
                    seqnum[0] =  str.Substring(0, indx).ToString();
                    seqnum[1] =  str.Substring(indx,str.Length-indx).ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }


         // output
        //  seqnum[0]=123.1.1.
        //  seqnum[1]=QWE
```

Comment: This will split the string 3 times.  Are people just trying answer this question with the worst way of splitting a string?